# how to update mysql table by c# code?

Tags: c#, mysql

this is mysql table

```
  reminder_id     date       show_day     before_day  status
   1            2016-06-05  1999-01-01         2        p
   2            2016-06-05  1999-01-01         1        p 
   3            2016-06-14  1999-01-01         2        p
   4            2016-06-25  1999-01-01         0        p
   5            2016-06-26  1999-01-01         4        p
```

---

i want to update the show_day column as (date-before_day)
in id 1 the show_day will be ('2016-06-05'-2)='2016-06-03'
in id 2 it will be ('2016-06-05'-1)='2016-06-01' and so on....

i write the below code but it update the whole column as same value of first id.
plz help me.

---

```
      void init2()
      {
         DateTime date = default(DateTime);
        int before_day = 0;
        DateTime sToday = DateTime.Now;
        string myConnection = "datasource= localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
        MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
        MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT* FROM bs.reminder ", myConn);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        myConn.Open();
        myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            date = myReader.GetDateTime(1);
            before_day = myReader.GetInt32(4);
            string show_day = date.AddDays(-before_day).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
            string constring = "datasource= localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
            string Query = "update bs.reminder set status='s',show_day='" + show_day + "' where status= 'p';";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader1;
            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader1 = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
                  while (myReader1.Read())
                {

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


        }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Why are you both opening a MySQL connection at the start of your code and then repeatedly opening one inside the loop? Only the first is needed, I think

Comment: it update the whole column as same value of first id

Comment: @vogomatix a second connection is needed because the first is 'busy' serving the first MySqlDataReader and cannot be used to execute the command. (Not sure if MARS is available in MySql)

Answer (score 1):

I would use ExecuteNonQuery instead of ExecuteReader.
And a parameterized query is always better than string concatenation.

However, the reason of the failed update is due to the missing information on the primary key in the WHERE clause. You need to add the `reminder_id` value to the WHERE to limit the update only to the specific record in the current external reader loop

```
int before_day = 0;
DateTime sToday = DateTime.Now;
string myConnection = "datasource= localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
using(MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection))
using(MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT* FROM bs.reminder ", myConn))
{
    myConn.Open();
    using(MySqlDataReader myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
       while (myReader.Read())
       {
            // get the remainder_id. It is the primary key to use in the update where
            int reminderid = myReader.GetInt32(0); 
            date = myReader.GetDateTime(1);
            before_day = myReader.GetInt32(4);

            DateTime show_day = date.AddDays(-before_day);
            string constring = "datasource= localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";

            // Update query that limits to just the current record (reminder_id)
            string Query = @"update bs.reminder set status='s',show_day=@newDay 
                             where reminder_id=@id and status= 'p';";

            using(MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring))
            using(MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase))
            {
                cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", reminderid);
                cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newDay", show_day);
                try
                {
                    conDataBase.Open();
                    int rowAffected = cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    ....
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another optimization could be the using statement to be sure to close and dispose the inner connection and command

Comment: Updated the answer with the condition on reminder_id. Refresh

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with your code, but the reason no update is occurring is you are missing

```
 cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

[I have to note that your variable naming could be better to aid understanding.]